# How to use from parameter in search api of Tweepy

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I am using [tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org/) python library for fetching data from twitter. I want to get tweet from ***user1*** tweeted to ***user3*** containing ***word1, word2, #hashText1*** etc.

```
query = "word1 word2 #hashtext1"
max_tweets = 10
searched_tweets = [status for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query, from='user2' to='user2').items(max_tweets)]
```

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to use **from** in the function as it is keyword in python.  When removed **from** parameter query works fine.

I have looked into source code of the tweepy [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/cd46550b3ef068857f5de9c37bbdd0a72acb7462/tweepy/api.py#L1207). It says from as valid parameter.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In depth Twitter Search API in tweepy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823430/in-depth-twitter-search-api-in-tweepy)