# In depth Twitter Search API in tweepy

Tags: tweepy

I wanted to search for tweets "by keyword" from a "given screen name."

Example, all tweets from "BBCNews" about "weather".

Looking into Tweepy library, I found this code:

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
              q="weather",
              rpp=100,
              result_type="recent",
              include_entities=True,
              lang="en")
```

However, how am I gonna filter the tweets such that they are only from 
BBCNews?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of options you can use to filter the tweets you find can be found here : https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

You can put them directly in your query, without caring about Tweepy.
In your case, I would suggest

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
              q="weather from:BBCNews",
              rpp=100,
              result_type="recent",
              include_entities=True,
              lang="en")
```

You can even add `-filter:retweets` to your request to get rid of the retweets.